# Merge DNS record tags for consistency

Tags: support, retag-request

I just asked a [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/417186/who-is-carrierzone-and-what-do-they-do-with-email-through-a-custom-domain) involving DNS MX records and noticed that there are two separate tags that appear to both concern MX records: [mx](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mx) and [mx-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mx-record).
Do these need to be merged?
Are there other tags in similar situations?

Comment: This seems reasonable - [tag:mx-record] should probably be the master tag for consistency with [tag:a-record] et. al.

Comment: Also merge [a-record] and [arecord]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there seem to be a few of these DNS-related tags let's collect them all in one place

- [mx-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mx-record) <- <s>[mx](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mx)</s>,
- [a-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/a-record)  <- <s>[arecord](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/arecord)</s>
- [soa-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/soa-record) <- <s>(Selective retagging of stuff in [soa](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/soa))</s>
- [cname-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cname-record) <- <s>[cname](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cname)</s>
- [ns-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ns-record) <- <s>[ns](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ns)</s>

Comment: mx-> mx-record and arecord -> a-record are done